# jquery autocomplete with json response

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, response

im getting response in json, but this wont parse the json response. what m i doing wrong? i could'nt find anything on doc http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

```
$("#users-allowed").autocomplete("/people/following.json", {
  width: 320,
  //max: 4,
  highlight: false,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 300,
  formatItem: function(response, i, max) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response['items']);
    console.log(response.items);
    return i + "/" + max + ": \"" + response.status_code + "\" [" + response.status_description + "]";

    //return "<img src='images/" + value + "'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
  },
  formatResult: function(response) {
    //return value.split(".")[0];
    return response.status_description;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$("#users-allowed").autocomplete("/people/following.json", {
  width: 320,
  dataType: 'json',
  highlight: false,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 300,
  parse: function(data) {
    var array = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<data.items.length;i++) {
      array[array.length] = { data: data.items[i], value: data.items[i], result: data.items[i].username };
    }
    return array;
  },
  formatItem: function(row) {               
    var name = '';
    if (row.first_name && row.last_name)
      name = '('+row.first_name+', '+row.last_name+')';
    else if (row.first_name)
      name = '('+row.first_name+')';
    else if (row.last_name)
      name = '('+row.last_name+')';

    return row.username+' '+name;
  }
});
```

check dataType and parse option.

Comment: Hi basit, I have the same problem, what is it that you did because I am getting a data.split is not a function

Comment: I tried to follow this answer and it doesn't work. the formatItem function argument is undefined.

Comment: if you want to automatically redirect to page after a selection use this code


     return row.username+''+name;
   }
}).result(function(event, selected) {
        location.href = selected.url_param_in_json_or_make_one;
    });

Comment: Also check your JSON is valid and well formed, obvious but a massive gotcha too.

Comment: ya like he said, make sure your json format is valid and all data in json are matching with the function, like items and so on.. else it will give error. it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Basit Mine loads the data on first character, but when I enter a new character, it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'toLowerCase'`. Ever had that problem before?

Answer (score 6):

I think you just need to throw in a `dataType` option, I remember readying that you can use any of `$.ajax`'s options in the autocompleter:

```
$("#users-allowed").autocomplete("/people/following.json", {
    dataType: "json",
    ...
```

Comment: with that im getting data.split is not a function
jquery/jquery.autocomplete.js
Line 11 error

Comment: btw im not using that function anywhere.. you can see above my code

Comment: @basit - because now you're working with an object, `split` is a function of type `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the options outside the scope of `$(document).ready(..)`

Ex:

```
var acCbo = {
        minChars: 1,
        delay:500,
        max: 100,
        width: 400,
        dataType: 'json', // this parameter is currently unused
        extraParams: {
            format: 'json', //pass the required context to the Zend Controller,
            filtro: 'id_procsianv,id_atividade',
            chave: function(){
                return $('#id_procsianv').val()+','+$('#id_atividade').val();
            }
        },
        queryParam: "descricao",
        parse: function(data) {
            if (data['qtde']>0){
                data = data['Cbo'];
                var parsed = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    parsed[parsed.length] = {
                        data: data[i],
                        value: data[i].id_cbo,
                        result: $('<textarea/>').html(data[i].no_cbo).val()
                    };
                }
                return parsed;
            }else{
                $('#id_cbo').val('');
                return [];
            }
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return item.no_cbo+ ' (' +item.id_cbo+ ')';
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#cbo').autocomplete('/cbos/index',acCbo)
    .result(function(e,data){
        $('#id_cbo').val(data.id_cbo);

    });
});
```