# Using getJSON data for autocomplete source

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Trying to first `.getJSON` then using that data to become the source of my autocomplete, heres the code.. this isn't working, what am i doing wrong here?

```
          $.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
                  //autocomplete
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                     $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                          minLength: 2,
                          source: data
                      })
                  });             
           });
```

I know i can do `source: url` but i don't want to make multiple calls to the jSON data.

Comment: "this isn't working": please elaborate

Comment: `source: url` works but `source: data` doesn't

Comment: remove the `$(document).ready()` wrapper function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to inverse the `document ready` event handler to wrap the `$.getJSON` aswell:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
         //autocomplete           
         $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
             minLength: 2,
             source: data
          })
    });             
});
```

Also, your data has to be an array. If its JSON, see this for reference: [jquery autocomplete with json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592048/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-response)

Comment: This method doesn't have much real world use.