# Client side searching for autocomplete() with JSON source

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

If i have a source for the `.autocomplete()` that is JSON, and like this:

```
[{
value: "jquery",
label: "jQuery",
desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
}]
```

No matter what i type into the input it still shows ALL of the JSON results.  I thought `.autocomplete()` would process the searching client side rather than expect the server to process it, maybe i'm wrong, because when you define an array as an object for the `source` it handles the client side searching for you, but how would i get it to act the same way from a JSON data source?

The code is here:

```
                  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {  
                  //autocomplete                     
                     $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
                          source: data,
                          minLength: 2
                      })                          
                  });
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have showing the `autocomplete` settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, [jquery autocomplete with json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592048/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-response)

It may help you.

Also, the autocomplete expects the data to be an array.

Comment: how do i make it an array? isn't `data` an array itself?
  `$.getJSON(url, function(data) {  });`

Comment: It has to be a true Array, not a JSON object. See the link, it has a code example.

Comment: ok, thats to get the source, how about the part of having it do client side searching ?

Comment: That example parses the JSON data as an array, so the autocomplete does its job.

Comment: Also, remember to set minLength to something above 1. This helps to improve performance and dont show the seach for a empty field (that returns all results) http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength