# jquery autocomplete c# List<string> as a source

Tags: c#, jquery, string, list, jquery-autocomplete

I have seen many examples where JQuery autocomplete gets a json response from code behind.  I seems a little counter productive to turn my list into json then back to an array of strings on client side.  I have a web method in code behind that returns a List of the results that I want the autocomplete to use, is there a way to just call that method from JQuery (I am very very new to JQuery, actually just started messing with it tonight).

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtbox").autocomplete({
           source :
```

Have no idea where to go from here...

Comment: Are using asp.net forms or MVC ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592048/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-response might help you

Comment: That question is for reading json response in JQuery, I am trying to see if there is a way to call a method that will return a simple string array or List right to JQuery

Comment: Remember that jQuery is JavaScript running on the client, while your web method is (presumably) C# running on the web server. In a conventional browser situation like this they are communicating via an http request from the client where the browser returns what is essentially a string. So no, you can't just call your web method directly from JavaScript (including jQuery) on the client. If you only want to convert the data once you could return html instead of JSON, though I'm not sure how that fits with the autoComplete jQuery plugin.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the answer, that sucks, on the bright side I always use XML because I know it well and I always avoid json because I don,t here's a good chance for me to learn , thanks

Comment: There's no problem using XML instead of JSON in a general sense, but again I don't know if the autoComplete jQuery plugin handles it (I would guess it handles JSON automatically). You should be able to tell your C# method to return a JSON reponse (don't be hand-coding JSON any more than you would hand-code XML).

Comment: is there a simple code to convert list to json with out downloading a json add on for .net?

Comment: if the autocomplete list is known at page render time, you can just include it as part of the page response.  Then you don't need another round trip or web method exposed.

Comment: how do I add it to page response? the list is known at Page_Init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Server side,

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public List<RetUsers> GetSomething()
{
//populate ur list here
  return list;
}
```

In Jquery,

```
 $("#txtbox").autocomplete({
           source : 'your url here'
```